# Android socket connection null pointer exception

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, connection

I have a problem with my socket connection. It says there is a null pionter exception in this line:

```
Socket client = new Socket(ip,8000);
```

But the Ip is OK, the port shoud be OK!

Here is the full code:

```
public class socket { 

public static void out(String out, Context context){

    final String PREFS_NAME = "SAVEDIP";
    final String PREF_IP = "";
    String ip = null;
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip = pref.getString(PREF_IP, "");
    Log.e("IP", ip);


    try {
        Socket client = new Socket(ip,8000);    
        //PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //output.println(out);
        Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //output.close();
        //in.close();
        client.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "UnknowHostExeption");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "IOExeption");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I'm passing the context and a text with this:

```
c = getApplicationContext();
socket.out("exit", c);
```

The error I get is the following:

```
    04-23 15:58:30.577: E/TAG(26540): IOExeption
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:115)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:244)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:219)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:781)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:194)
04-23 15:58:30.577: W/System.err(26540):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:258)
04-23 15:58:30.587: W/System.err(26540):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:222)
04-23 15:58:30.587: W/System.err(26540):    at com.example.andremote.socket.out(socket.java:28)
04-23 15:58:30.587: W/System.err(26540):    at com.example.andremote.Remote$11.onClick(Remote.java:175)
04-23 15:58:30.587: W/System.err(26540):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-23 15:58:30.597: W/System.err(26540):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
04-23 15:58:30.597: W/System.err(26540):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-23 15:58:30.597: W/System.err(26540):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 15:58:30.597: W/System.err(26540):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-23 15:58:30.597: W/System.err(26540):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
04-23 15:58:30.607: W/System.err(26540):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 15:58:30.607: W/System.err(26540):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 15:58:30.607: W/System.err(26540):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-23 15:58:30.607: W/System.err(26540):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-23 15:58:30.607: W/System.err(26540):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please tell me where I made a mistake, I cant find the solotiun!

Answer (score 0):

apparently at this line

```
ip = pref.getString(PREF_IP, "");
```

on right side null is returned so your ip variable still get null or invalidate value so when you pass it to Socket constructor as parameter since your ip variable(host name) is invalid it produces IOException. Try to check your ip variable against null or before pass it to Socket constructor.

Comment: I checked it for null, but its not null. It is 192.168.1.2 as it should be :(